# How pass variables for alternative if -syntax?

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
 $a=3;
 $dir= '/php/';
?>
 <?php if($a ==3){ ?>
<form action="/php/form.php" method="post">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to pass  $dir in form action ,like action=$dir.form.php. It's possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible you need to simply pass `$dir` to action Try

```
<form action="<?php echo $dir;?>form.php" method="post">
```

Comment: glad to know it's helpful for you you can accept/upvote helpful answers

Comment: @RakeshSharma There's a time limit until the OP can accept. + if you ask me, +50 for this simple answer is rewarding enough :).

Comment: @DaveChen i know :) i am suggesting only

Answer (score 1):

You can embed php tags anywhere in your html code. Rewrite your snippet like this:

```
<?php 
   $a=3;
   $dir= '/php/';
 ?>
 <?php if($a ==3){ ?>
<form action="<?php echo $dir."form.php" ?>" method="post">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

```
 <?php 
 $a=3;
 $dir= '/php/';

 if($a ==3){ ?>
   <form action="<?php echo $dir.'form.php'; ?>" method="post">
   <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```